# Edited title doesn't update in the navigation bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, title

After editing a question and returning to the question page, the page is updated to reflect any edits. The question title in the navigation bar however doesn't update—leaving us with two different titles visible.

Pulling down for a page refresh does update the navigation bar to show the correct title, but since everything else updates it would make sense to update the navigation bar too.

An example of mismatching titles after an edit:

> [image]

---

- App Version: 1.6.1.2
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.0.1 (Build 14A403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.2.1.

Comment: MFW official dev reply ends up in LQP automatically.