# Update the document title and URL after an inline question edit is submitted that edits the title

Tags: feature-request, inline-editor

After title edits are submitted using the inline question editor, the [browsing context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Browsing_context) (webpage)'s [document `<title>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-title-element) and [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) are not updated. The update will only be reflected in the browsing context's document title and URL (as observable by `window.location` and the URL bar in a browser's [chrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=User_interface_chrome&redirect=no)) if/after the user refreshes the page.

Changing the text of a `<title>` is pretty simple (`document.querySelector("title").innerText = ...`), and changing the URL can be done with [`History.replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState) (or [`History.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState), but since it's an inline edit, I think `replaceState` makes more sense).

<sup>Possibly related to the document title (a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) bug report): [Edited title doesn't update in the navigation bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286989/997587)</sup>

Make it so?